# Get SQL Server 2005 sort varchar columns just as Java would do

Tags: sql-server, sorting

My problem is very simple: I have an array of String. Sorting it in Java gives one order , and in Sql Server 2005 slightly different order . An example of difference I spotted was in the case of two strings: "jyl ; pagespro" , "jyl" , which Java sorts in this order, and Sql in the inverse order .
I tried to make Sql Server order by ascii(myColumn) but still with no effect. How can I solve this ??.....

Comment: Have you tried specifying sort order with ASC or DESC for ascending or descending?

Comment: YES of course , there are ASC . And I need that

Comment: Can you edit your question to just say what order you what SQL to sort your data in? The way Java does it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: If i am understanding the question correctly; he just need to use `ASC` or `DESC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend on DaveE's answer, if you have determined the collation you want to use for sorting, you can use its name in the ORDER BY clause like this:
`ORDER BY colA COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CS_AS_KI_WI`.

Please be aware that this would not use an index for sorting that might be defined on `colA`. You could get around that by using calculated columns.

In general, I would suggest to do all sorting in one place: either in Java, or in the database, but not sometimes here and sometimes there. This just leads to confusion and complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect it has to do with the SQL Server [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in effect. That affects not only the available character set but also how the characters sort against one another.  Even in the   fairly generic SQL_Latin1_General family, there are dozens of specific collations available.